# how i can get parameter value in plugin into magento 2 observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account, plugin

i have plugin for customer account create

```
public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Create $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $getid = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('param_id');


        return $proceed();
    }
```

the URL

```
http://localhost/magento/customer/account/create/?param_id=20
```

> I'm getting the value 20 in that plugin
>
> **I want to pass the value to customer registration success observer**
>
> how i can do this????

Comment: Add your logic directly before  return $proceed();;

Comment: how i can pass the value to observer

Comment: What is the observer you want to catch?

Comment: that param_Id in url

Comment: You can write your code in aroundExecute function what you want to write in your observer

Comment: http://localhost/magento/customer/account/create/?param_id=20   i given that url to  browser it will redirect to sign up page

Comment: after clicking sign up button redirect to success page 

i write observer for that but i'm not getting parameter id here ..(*customer_register_success* event)

Comment: @Ranganathan check your mail bro